# Arrays not behaving as expected in Tic Tac Toe?

Tags: c++, arrays

I made tictactoe! ...almost.

The code:

```
int main()
{
    //initialize
    char board[3][3] =
    {   '-','-','-',
        '-','-','-',
        '-','-','-'};
    bool gameOver = false;
    std::string playerTurn = "player 1";
    char chX, chY; //choice x and y
    int x = 1;

    //game loop
    do
    {
        std::cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
        std::cout << "Input X, then Y.\np1 = X, p2 = O.";
        std::cout << "\n\nTurn: " << playerTurn;
        std::cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
        std::cout << "+---+---+---+" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "| " << board[0][0] << " | " << board[0][1] << " | " << board[0][2] << " | " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "+---+---+---+" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "| " << board[1][0] << " | " << board[1][1] << " | " << board[1][2] << " | " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "+---+---+---+" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "| " << board[2][0] << " | " << board[2][1] << " | " << board[2][2] << " | " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "+---+---+---+" << std::endl;

        //get input and change board's value
        std::cin >> chX;
        std::cin >> chY;
        if (playerTurn == "player 1")
            board[chX][chY] = 'X';
        else if (playerTurn == "player 2")
            board[chX][chY] = 'O';

        //change turns
        if (playerTurn == "player 1")
            playerTurn = "player 2";
        else if (playerTurn == "player 2")
            playerTurn = "player 1";

    } while (gameOver == false);
    return 0;
}
```

my problem:

```
//get input and change board's value
std::cin >> chX;
std::cin >> chY;
if (playerTurn == "player 1")
    board[chX][chY] = 'X';
else if (playerTurn == "player 2")
    board[chX][chY] = 'O';
```

This piece is for changing the X and Y coordinates to an X / O depending on who's turn it is.  However this doesn't change the board at all, and doesn't return an error.
Also: `board[0][0] = 't';` will successfully change the value, and print `t` in the `[0][0]` spot.

Is there something I'm missing?  Maybe the problem is elsewhere in the code?
(I apologize in advance if the problem is way too simple -- maybe I have had too much coffee.)

Comment: @s.bandara playerTurn is a `std::string` that ok to compare it to a string litteral.

Comment: Overall I'd recommend against storing player turn information as a `string`. You could do with a smaller, simpler datatype as well.

Comment: Can you show the input your entering ?

Comment: I threw it in there as a plain concept and never took it out, I didn't think it was too efficient.  You people are thorough, I knew someone would get on me about that. :D I will change it soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a small mistake - you defined chX and chY as char, and if the user enters e.g. '1', it's the ASCII code for '1', not the integer value 1.

Just change your declaration to

```
  int chX, chY;
```

and it should work.

Comment: Bah.  Should have caught that.  THank you!

Comment: I was in the process of entering the same answer, you win. :)

Answer (score 0):

Right change chY and chX from chars to ints cause thats how arrays are indexed.

Then use this for your input code

```
std::cout << "Enter X corrdinate: ";
std::cin >> chX;
std::cout << "\n";
std::cin.clear();
std::cout << "Enter Y corrdinate: ";
std::cin >> chY;
std::cin.clear();
if (playerTurn == "player 1")
    board[chX][chY] = 'X';
else if (playerTurn == "player 2")
    board[chX][chY] = 'O';
```

Id also create a second array board of type int so you can examine whether a player has won easier

Answer (score 0):

```
char chX,chY; // valid values -127..128
std::cin >> chX; //gets ascii code of '0', '1' or whichever value you enter
std::cin >> chY;
```

The problem is cin will return the ascii code of characters you enter; '0'=48; To get the integer value simply subtract the '0':

```
  std::cin >> chX; 
    std::cin >> chY;
    chX -= '0';
    chy -= '0';
```